# Background colour to text. Space in between. Lines same width. Padding on lines

Tags: html, css

I have a block of text that I need to give a background colour to the individual lines with space in between.

I have partially achieved this with

```
<div class="styleText">
    <span class="spaced">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</span>
</div>
```

.

```
.styleText .spaced{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,6.5); 
    line-height: 1.2em; 
    /*width: 421px;*/
}
```

However, I need all the lines to be the same width and would like padding at the start and end as well as top and bottom of each line.

Can anyone think of a way to achieve this effect or is my only option to employ some background image trickery to the styleText class?

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: no, you can't do that with just CSS. Paddings are applied to block elements only and your lines aren't blocks for sure..

Comment: can you add an image with the result you want to acheive? I'm having a hard time understanding what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved the effect using a background image:

```
.styleText{width: 387px; position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; background: url(../images/styledTextBG.png) 0 2px; padding: 0 17px}
.styleText .spaced{line-height: 35px; display: inline; min-width: 421px;}
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

(obv, I still need to style the text)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible

```
.styleText{
    background: url(...); 
    width: 420px;
    height:300px;
    border:solid black 1px;
    padding:2%;
}

span.spaced{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,6.5);
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    width: 95%;
    text-align:justify;
    margin:2px auto;
    line-height:1em;
    opacity:0.7;
    font-size:14px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70)
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/crLJ5/17/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think I explained myself very clearly in my initial post. I've added an image to show what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks again, however I need this piece of text to be CMS editable so it's not feasible to separate it into different blocks. I have found a solution using background images. Will post shortly.